# Retrieve and modify :before element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I want to select an element which was created by the CSS selector `:before`.

I tried it by using `$('#element:before')`, but that did not work, because it selected the whole element and not only the `:before` element.

Here is the sample code: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/qGStB/)

In that example, only the string "1. " should be red, not the whole string. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: `:before` doesn't create an element, so you can't select it. You can do this though http://jsfiddle.net/qGStB/2/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Manipulating CSS :before and :after pseudo-elements using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/manipulating-css-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-using-jquery)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JQuery cannot set css properties on :before content, since it is not contained in an element. If you want to be able to manipulate the color of the :before content with javascript, you can create an extra css class, and add/remove this class.

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/qGStB/4/)

Comment: if i follow your approach and assumed that the color can have 100 different values, i'd need to create 100 css classes. that does not feel very elegant.

Comment: That is correct. If you really have to be able to set a lot of different values, you cannot use the css content and css :before selector. Consider using a span element instead, this will give you much more control.

Comment: I agree with @aaberg a span element is much nicer in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You can't target the content created with css `:before`. You can however target a data element and add that to the content tag in css. See for this the accepted answer on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/manipulating-css-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-using-jquery).

Also styling with css is possible if you want that is your goal:

```
div:before {
    content: '1. ';
    color:red;
}
```

Will only make the 1. red.

Comment: the css-only solution is not an option because i need to change the attribute (in this example the color) dynamically. therefore there is the need for some jquery magic. the `attr()` method does not seem to work with other attributes than with content, which is not useful in this case.

Answer (score 1):

A way can be the `custom properties`, practically css variables.

[Here the compatibilities](https://caniuse.com/css-variables)

[Here a bit of documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties)

And an example where the variable `--myColor` have a global scope because declared under `:root`:

```js
setInterval(function() {  
  
  $(':root').css('--myColor', 'red');

}, 2000);
```

```css
:root {
  
  --myColor: green;
  
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
div:before {
    content: '1. ';
    color: var(--myColor);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  test
</div>
```