# Jquery :before and Css

Tags: jquery, css, colors, addclass, toggleclass

I have a div.
In my CSS, I added ':before' to this div for create an other color block over it.

In jquery, I want to change the color on the mouseover but only for the "div:before" block, but it doesn't work.

How can I solve my problem ?

Thks

**[MY JS FIDDLE PROBLEM](http://jsfiddle.net/N5RLU/1/)**

**My CSS :**

```
div {
    background:cyan;
    width:200px;
    height:300px;
}

div.color:before {
    content:'Color me !';
    background:orange;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
}
```

**My jQuery :**

```
$('div').addClass('color');

$("div").toggleClass("color").mouseover(function() {  
    $(this).stop().css({  'background':'#FF0000' }); 
    });

$("div").toggleClass("color").mouseout(function() {  
    $(this).stop().css({  'background':'#FFFF00' }); 
    });
```

Comment: Start here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5814810/target-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-with-jquery and follow to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-using-jquery-e-g-before-and-after and then http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/#Not_supported

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to change the properties of: "before", but you can get what you want with classes modoicando class of his element, as shown here

[Retrieve and modify :before element with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071408/retrieve-and-modify-before-element-with-jquery)